# Different results in Chi-Square test

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the Chi-Square result for a simply data table

I have two groups, let's call them PG and KG. PG has in category 1 19 values and in category 2 11 values. KG has in category 1 0 values and in category 2 30 values.

The python code would be

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

observed = [[0, 30], [19, 11]]

chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(observed)

print("Chi Square value:", chi2)
```

This yields 24.95.  But when using Stata or the online calculator https://mathcracker.com/de/chi-quadrat-test-unabhangigkeit, I get 27.80. I don't understand where the difference comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's parameter [`correction=`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html#scipy.stats.chi2_contingency), which is in default mode set to `True`:

```
correction bool, optional

If True, and the degrees of freedom is 1, apply Yates’ correction for
continuity. The effect of the correction is to adjust each observed
value by 0.5 towards the corresponding expected value.
```

---

```py
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

observed = [[0, 30], [19, 11]]

chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(observed, correction=False)

print("Chi Square value:", chi2)
```

Prints:

```
Chi Square value: 27.804878048780488
```

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks! But what should be set in my case, True or False? Does it depend on the type of data?

Comment: @Tornado According this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates's_correction_for_continuity) it depends on your type of data.